# Is abusing Application.UnhandledException for login redirection okay?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I'm programming a windows phone 7 app which needs authentication for news-like read access.
I use Application.UnhandledException to handle (my) `AuthFailedException`, which can be thrown from any page, and navigate to a login page.

To mimic a modal dialog, I do the following:

1. I attach a `BackKeyPress` event handler to clear the back stack, effectively causing the app to exit.
2. On login, I invoke the actual go-back behavior to get back to the previous page, which 
   threw the `AuthFailedException` (all in the view model via proper dependency injection).

This feels dirty, but at least a little better than what hacks might be neccessary otherwise... Any advice on how to improve the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guideline that you shouldn't use exceptions for flow control exists, in part, because exceptions can be orders of magnitude slower than a simple`if` statement.  But you can *handle* an exception, especially a lone one, and that's exactly what you're doing here.

Revel in the mosh pit.  It's OK.